# angular click trigger not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to trigger angular element click event to trigger while loading the page

```
$scope.fetchMealInfo = function (incomingDate) {
    angular.element(".trackNext a").on("click", function () {
        //alert(offset.left);
        console.log("inside click event");
        if (contentDiv.scrollLeft() < (offset.left - 317)) //contentDiv.scrollLeft(contentDiv.scrollLeft() + 254);
            contentDiv.animate({
            scrollLeft: contentDiv.scrollLeft() + 317
        });
    });
    plzzer();
}
```

function plzzer is

```
window.plzzer=function() {
    console.log("inside plzzer");
    angular.element(".trackNext a").trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: Did you getting any error in console?Also please share the html part for trackNext

Comment: Add your HTML code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of requerying in the second method, have you tried triggering the event straight off of the listener?

```
$scope.fetchMealInfo = function (incomingDate) {
    angular.element(".trackNext a").on("click", function () {
        console.log("inside click event");
        if (contentDiv.scrollLeft() < (offset.left - 317)) {
            contentDiv.animate({
                 scrollLeft: contentDiv.scrollLeft() + 317
            });
        } 
    }).click();
}
```

Comment: how to call click event multiple times

Comment: $("#foo").click(function() {
    console.log('clicked');
}).click().click().click().click();

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to trigger Click event on page load, you can do it this way : 
$scope.fetchMealInfo();